# PyZMQ and Django: connection from different view

Tags: python, django, zeromq, pyzmq

I am writing a Django web application where the user can do different operations from every view and when the user submit the form a JSON is pushed to ZeroMQ and waits for a response (REQ-REP).

My problem is that the operations are too slow. I don't know if the problems occur becouse I am using a low performance Debian virtualized in VirtualBox but I think the problem is that when I call the function (see below), I do a new connection every time and the connection take like 5 seconds.

```
def push(obj):
    try:
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
        socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888')
        socket.send_json(obj)
        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        if poller.poll(3*1000):
            socket.recv()
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
    finally:
        socket.close()
        context.term()
```

This is the other side code:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888')

while True:
    obj = str(socket.recv_json())
    print obj
    socket.send('ACK')
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe should I think I need to keep the connection opened for all the user session, but how? Any tips are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the code from the other side ?

Comment: Ok, there is nothing strange on the other side. Can you add some prints between the steps ? For sure you don't have to (actually it's a bad practice) to destroy the context every time, and you should keep the socket open, but I'd like to see where the delay is.

Comment: I am sure that the delay is in this step: socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888')

Comment: If you are sure the issue is with connect, there are not many explanations with the connect. The main one is the other socket is not ready on time (although zmq should handle that transparently). Is the delay present from the first request ?

Comment: I think the problem ins not the first request i have tried to send in loop 1000 times the object and after the connect, send and recv works very fast, like instantly. it's normal that the connect takes like 5 seconds? Can it be a problem of the OS virtualized in VirtualBox?

Comment: No, it's not normal. I'm routinely working with vagrant boxes with 1 core and 512MB ram and there no such delays. Can you try keeping the context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finelly solved the problem unistalling libzmq-dev installed from debian repository (I think I was using 2.2 but I am not sure) and installing PyZMQ and ZMQ using pip with this command:

```
pip install --no-use-wheel pyzmq
```

I am not sure which version is installed now or which version is the best for a stable production environment with python 2.7, but it works fast now!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)  Please be sure to accept your own answer so that the rest of the community knows your problem is solved.